# Writing a program to add all the odd numbers in an array

Tags: javascript

```
 // Write a program to sum all the odd elements of an array

    a = Number(prompt("a:"));
    b = Number(prompt("b:"));
    c = Number(prompt("c:"));

    sum=Number(0);

    var test = [a,b,c];

    for (i=0; i<test.length;i++) {
        // All even numbers can be divided by 2
        if ((test[i]%2)>0) {
            alert(test[i] + ":odd");
        } else {
            alert(test[i] + ":even");
        }
        test[i]=0;
   }

   sum=0+test[i];
   alert(sum);
```

My program works brilliant up until its meant to add up all the numbers where it returns a NaN message! Any ideas on how I can sort this problem out?

Comment: Values input from a prompt are strings, not numbers-that should be enough of a hint.

Comment: I see a second problem, in that how you sum will always equal the last number added, it isn't summing, but setting.

Comment: @Dave: Except that `Number('11') + Number('23')` is 34.

Comment: @muistooshort Doh! Huh. I'm not even sure what I was looking at now; although it baffles (and scares) me that I guess two other people were looking at the same non-existent thing :/

Comment: I edited a bit both for clarity, but also to show what you were actually executing in your if statement with the `%` operator. (One reason why brackets are almost always a good idea.)

Comment: `Number('11') + Number('foo'); // NaN` -- you should still validate your input.

Comment: @Dave Newton - you should post your edit as an answer (even though it competes with my answer), because as you say it makes it fairly obvious what is going wrong.

Comment: @nnnnnn Nah; it's my penance for my complete brain fart on the initial reading :/

Comment: With your edit, if you have test[i]=0; inside the loop you will only get zeroes in your array and never get the sum you are looking for (if you sum the numbers correctly, because right now you are trying to sum outside the for loop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see three problems with your code. (Not counting the weird formatting of the curly brackets.)

1. *Edit: looks like the question has been updated a couple of times since I started my answer.*<s>In the "if odd" test you are setting the number to zero with</s>  Perhaps you meant to zero out the even numbers so that you could later add up all the numbers and just get the odd ones, but `test[i]=0` is not part of the if/else structure. It looks like it *should* be because of the indenting, but JavaScript ignores extra white-space.
2. You are not adding the numbers to the `sum` within your loop.
3. You are getting NaN because of this line:

   ```
   sum=0+test[i];
   ```

That statement is outside the end of the loop, so at that point `i` is equal to the length of the array and `test[i]` is `undefined`.

Try the following pseudo-code:

```
sum = 0
for (loop through the array) {
   if current number is odd
      sum = sum + current number
}
```

Comment: `sum += current number ` even

Comment: @btleffler - yes, I definitely would code it that way, but I deliberately didn't say it because it seems like jeansymolanza is confused enough without introducing more operators...

Answer (score 4):

Your sum (sum=0+test[i];) is outside the for loop. You should move it inside the for loop to get the sum in your "sum" variable.

Answer (score 4):

```
var A= [17, 6, 19, 27, 56, 73, 43, 70, 41, 48, 
10, 69, 22, 71, 53, 11, 40, 72, 32, 25, 14, 54, 
13, 38, 62, 66, 2, 37, 60, 75, 52, 33, 58, 30, 
61, 5, 57, 49, 21, 34, 67, 51, 16, 45, 64, 24, 
23, 20, 47, 65, 46, 18, 1, 44, 15, 42, 68, 26, 
74, 7, 55, 36, 8, 50, 9, 59, 31, 3, 4, 29, 
35, 39, 63, 12, 28];

A.filter(function(i){return i%2}).reduce(function(a, b){return a+b});
```

**returned value: (Number) 1444**

```
//equalizer for old browsers
if(![].filter){
    Array.prototype.filter= function(fun, scope){
        var T= this, A= [], i= 0, itm, L= T.length;
        if(typeof fun== 'function'){
            while(i< L){
                if(i in T){
                    itm= T[i];
                    if(fun.call(scope, itm, i, T)) A[A.length]= itm;
                }
                ++i;
            }
        }
        return A;
    }
}
if(![].reduce){
    Array.prototype.reduce= function(fun, temp, scope){
        var T= this, i= 0, len= T.length, temp;
        if(typeof fun=== 'function'){
            if(temp== undefined) temp= T[i++];
            while(i < len){
                if(i in T) temp= fun.call(scope, temp, T[i], i, T);
                i++;
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }
}
```